# Similarity metrics for circular and unaligned time series

Tags: time-series, similarities

I face the problem of calculating the similarity between multiple time series. What I want to do is compare each one with the first one to quantify the degree of change.

The challenge is that they are circulant and not aligned, similarity measures like euclidean distance dont really seem promising.

I was thinking of dynamic time warping, but it seems unable to distinguish between very light changes and significant changes properly, returning a similar score for both cases.

Can anyone think of a similarity metric suitable for this case?

Comment: Have you thought about extracting features then comparing the similarity of features? See https://robjhyndman.com/publications/ts-clustering/index.html